# Google map input box autocomplete is not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

This is my code. Here map is working fine for me, issue only for input box autocomplete is not working for me.please guide me to fix this issue.................................................................................

```
 **HTML**   


<input type="text"name="newWardName" id="newWardName" placeholder="Enter Ward Name"/>
<div>
        <div id="googleMap" ></div>
        <input id="latitudeId" name="latitudeName" placeholder="Latitude"/>
        <input id="longitudeId" name="longitudeName" placeholder="Longitude"/>
    </div>

**JavaScript**
function initialize()
    {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(12.961735, 77.588195);
        var mapProp = {
            center:myCenter,
            zoom:12,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        var input = document.getElementById('newWardName');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
            types: ["geocode"]
        });
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

            placeMarker(event.latLng);
            console.log("on click of map", (event.latLng));
        });
    }

    var marker;
    function placeMarker(location) {
        if (!marker) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
        } else {
            marker.setPosition(location);
        }
        document.getElementById("latitudeId").value = location.lat();
        document.getElementById("longitudeId").value = location.lng();
    }
```

Thanks in advance
Math

Comment: Your code as it is works for me. Did you [load the places-library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library)?

Comment: @Dr.Molle thanks for your quick replay. i tried place-library which you given, is not working to me. am using this one " http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true "  can check this.

Comment: As I said, your code works for me(even with the linked API-version), the provided informations are not sufficient to be able to solve it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7dkcmg2L/

Comment: @Dr.Molle. finally i found my error . calling map api two times . now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found my error . calling map api two times, now it is working fine.

Comment: Callin' api map 2 times...where? I'm in the same problem and can't figure it out...